# test file name before job

Tags: csv, spring-batch

am trying to use spring batch to import data from csv files to database ,what am trying to do is test if the directory isEmpty and the file names -it has to match a certain pattern  before the job starts if it matchs it should launch the job and read the file if not then move it to a rejected folder.The question is where do i do the testing part i tried puting it before the ItemReader

```
 @Bean
      public FlatFileItemReader<SMS> reader(){
          try {
            //here//
            }
            
        
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
          
          FlatFileItemReader<SMS> CSVReader=new FlatFileItemReader<SMS>();
          CSVReader.setLinesToSkip(1);
          CSVReader.setName("SMSItemReader");
          CSVReader.setResource(new ClassPathResource(fileInput+""));
          CSVReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper());
         
        return CSVReader;
      }
```

But didn't work , and couldn't put it in the step because it should return a step either way , am lost could anybody help me Pleease

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not supposed to write such code in a bean definition method. This method is intended to define an item reader bean. What you are trying to do is suitable for a `JobExecutionDecider` (this is one option among many others). A job execution decider is where you can put logic to decide if your job should be executed or not, like checking the directory content and file name pattern in your case.

You can find more details and a code example in the [Programmatic Flow Decisions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/step.html#programmaticFlowDecisions) section of the documentation.

Comment: can i use listeners like ItemReadListener instead  in my case i have to implement the test before the reading process

Comment: If you want to use a listener, then a `JobExecutionListener` (or `StepExecutionListener`) is more suitable than an `ItemReadListener` IMO, as the whole step execution depends on the condition you are checking.